# Javascript: Problems structuring array of JSON objects as a script

Tags: javascript, command-line

I am creating a local html page to serve as a viewer for videos I have downloaded with youtube-dl. In order for the viewer to work it needs to be able to access the video metadata. I can easily pipe the metadata output from youtube-dl when it finishes a download as json into a single text file using a batch operation. That file looks like this and has a different json object on each line:

```
{Id: "jYDgJjGfha", description: "This video isn't good at all"}
{Id: "JDRegIIGfj", description: "This video is terrible"}
{Id: "VkdwjDoG", description: "Why am I downloading these?"}
```

However, because of cross origin protections it is impossible for me to get the file on my html viewer page.

It was suggested to me that instead of trying to load the text file with the metadata into my page that I convert the metadata into a valid script and load it with the script tag (e.g., `<script src="metadata.js"></script>`).

In the batch file it was simple to make the first line of the file equal to `const database = [` and append a comma every time a line of json is output. This is what the file containing the metadata looks like now:

```
const database = [
{Id: "jYDgJjGfha", description: "This video isn't good at all"},
{Id: "JDRegIIGfj", description: "This video is terrible"},
{Id: "VkdwjDoG", description: "Why am I downloading these?"},
```

However, I do not have a way of closing this array. Because for every new video that becomes available when the batch file is run new lines will need to be appended. I also cannot use solutions that require loading the entire metadata file into memory because it is a very large file.

I've thought of a couple of different ways to structure my metadata script file, but none of them seem to quite meet my needs:

For example: This approach might work, but I have no way of finding out the correct index to set my line to when appending it in the batch file;

```
const database = [];
database[0] = {Id: "jYDgJjGfha", description: "This video isn't good at all"};
database[1] = {Id: "JDRegIIGfj", description: "This video is terrible"};
database[2] = {Id: "VkdwjDoG", description: "Why am I downloading these?"};
```

And this approach would definitely work, but I'm worried about it's performance on my large file:

```
const database = [];
database.push(database [I] = {Id: "jYDgJjGfha", description: "This video isn't good at all"});
database.push({Id: "JDRegIIGfj", description: "This video is terrible"});
database.push({Id: "VkdwjDoG", description: "Why am I downloading these?"});
```

Are there different ways I can structure my metadata script file to make it into a valid script?

**Edit**
I was actually able to achieve the originally desired file structure by changing my batch file to a PowerShell script. [See](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56854206/append-text-before-tail-in-large-file).
I've marked @lima_fil's answer as correct because it is still a valid answer to my question and could help someone down the line.

Comment: `However, because of cross origin protections it is impossible for me to get the file on my html viewer page.` If you control the server, cross origin is not a problem.

Comment: Sorry I should have specified, this is for a local html file only. There is and will not be a server.

Comment: Is there a reason for not using browser storage provider? like localStorage, sessionStorage or even indexedb?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe because I'd have to use different methods for different browsers. Aiming to have as little code as possible.

Comment: @FunkyKong The API of localStorage for example (applies for the rest as well) is standardized i.e you are going to use it in same way across the most popular browsers.If you need to save your data (sessions) then maybe storage is what you need, otherwise the way you've started your implementation might be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Playing with a String can give you more freedom. Eg:
Create a String instead of an array, than convert it to array.

```
var dbString = '[null' 
+ ',{"Id": "JDRegIIGfj", "description": "This video is terrible"}' 
+ ',{"Id": "VkdwjDoG", "description": "Why am I downloading these?"}'
```

Than convert it to Array:

```
var dbArray = JSON.parse(window.dbString + ']');
```

Note that Object should be in JSON format {"key": "value"}.