# Append text before tail in large file

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use PowerShell to create a NoSQL JSON database based on the print output of youtube-dl. Every time a video downloads it prints a JSON formatted string which I need to append into my NoSQL database. However, for my database to be read by my viewer application I need the character `]` to always remain on the last line, meaning when I insert the JSON lines they need to be above that. However, given the amount of videos I am going to download I have calculated my nosql database will become a very large file.

This is my current PowerShell script:

```bsh
Write-Host "Searching for and downloading videos . . . "
if (![System.IO.File]::Exists('.\database.js')) {
    Set-Content -Path .\database.js -Value "const database = [
]"
}
youtube-dl.exe --config-location config.txt --print-json >> database.js
Read-Host -Prompt "Done, press Enter to exit"
```

This is what my `database.js` file should look like ideally:

```json
const database = [
{"id": "Zre0TRsGVsA", "uploader": "an0nymooose", "uploader_id": "an0nymooose", "uploader_url": "http://www.youtube.com/user/an0nymooose", "channel_id": "UCpclRlEJ2oh6JDEJy68UjKA", "channel_url": "http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCpclRlEJ2oh6JDEJy68UjKA", "upload_date": "20160406", "license": null, "creator": null, "title": "[SFM] Marco Bros", "alt_title": null, "thumbnail": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Zre0TRsGVsA/maxresdefault.jpg", "description": "i'll show myself out\n\nI've been super busy, ill still make cool stuff dont worry.\nSource\nhttps://soundcloud.com/regnidlab-paej-rolyat/it-was-your-fault", "categories": ["Film & Animation"], "tags": ["sfm mario", "anonymoose", "an0nymoose", "source film maker"], "subtitles": {}, "automatic_captions": {}, "duration": 19, "age_limit": 0, "annotations": null, "chapters": null, "webpage_url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zre0TRsGVsA", "view_count": 1343237, "like_count": 30493, "dislike_count": 245, "average_rating": 4.9681177, "formats": [{"format_id": "249", "url": "https://r3---sn-5aapxquxaxjvh-p5qe.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1562102342&ei=5nUbXaTpKYu38gSFxpKABg&ip=205.201.245.3&id=o-AIQyMAv9KAgXr7OP25tqJ3GonDqvQCK1eXYzI5QA5hM0&itag=249&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-5aapxquxaxjvh-p5qe%2Csn-p5qs7n76&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=2&pl=20&initcwndbps=1252500&mime=audio%2Fwebm&gir=yes&clen=118049&dur=18.701&lmt=1559546502364814&mt=1562080584&fvip=6&keepalive=yes&c=WEB&txp=5432432&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cmime%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=ALgxI2wwRgIhAJkKbG91rpZ-GaMSW_lUsNPZVQaQ16lT6d5s_AdInwZAAiEAvcqdDVrR6H092E3n0zss6L6Iat79RGITr2f-QvnySJM%3D&lsparams=mm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=AHylml4wRgIhAJz3ixqopsu5l8C_jzP-E4EzYnxGBFIC7XGGjD4BRPyIAiEAxoV0lO0XBysnXt8k50Q7F5J7Yig9lS3Xc25XOvHeODo%3D&ratebypass=yes", "player_url": "/yts/jsbin/player_ias-vflxACNZ2/en_US/base.js", "ext": "webm", "format_note": "DASH audio", "acodec": "opus", "abr": 50, "filesize": 118049, "tbr": 52.326, "quality": -1, "vcodec": "none", "downloader_options": {"http_chunk_size": 10485760}, "format": "249 - audio only (DASH audio)", "protocol": "https", "http_headers": {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0", "Accept-Charset": "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7", "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8", "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", "Accept-Language": "en-us,en;q=0.5"}}, {"format_id": "250", "url": "https://r3---sn-5aapxquxaxjvh-p5qe.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1562102342&ei=5nUbXaTpKYu38gSFxpKABg&ip=205.201.245.3&id=o-AIQyMAv9KAgXr7OP25tqJ3GonDqvQCK1eXYzI5QA5hM0&itag=250&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-5aapxquxaxjvh-p5qe%2Csn-p5qs7n76&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=2&pl=20&initcwndbps=1252500&mime=audio%2Fwebm&gir=yes&clen=153599&dur=18.701&lmt=1559546502464967&mt=1562080584&fvip=6&keepalive=yes&c=WEB&txp=5432432&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cmime%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=ALgxI2wwRAIge6NHeiSSt0S5ozyQf9o0bW6ddEzcal2rRXPogceLWf0CIAPdRticAWQz6VvPG5MUTtg-t8EubtuJyC7lInCLt0uz&lsparams=mm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=AHylml4wRgIhAJz3ixqopsu5l8C_jzP-E4EzYnxGBFIC7XGGjD4BRPyIAiEAxoV0lO0XBysnXt8k50Q7F5J7Yig9lS3Xc25XOvHeODo%3D&ratebypass=yes", "player_url": "/yts/jsbin/player_ias-vflxACNZ2/en_US/base.js", "ext": "webm", "format_note": "DASH audio", "acodec": "opus", "abr": 70, "filesize": 153599, "tbr": 68.228, "quality": -1, "vcodec": "none", "downloader_options": {"http_chunk_size": 10485760}, "format": "250 - audio only (DASH audio)", "protocol": "https", "http_headers": {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0", "Accept-Charset": "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7", "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8", "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", "Accept-Language": "en-us,en;q=0.5"}}, {"format_id": "251", "url": "https://r3---sn-5aapxquxaxjvh-p5qe.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1562102342&ei=5nUbXaTpKYu38gSFxpKABg&ip=205.201.245.3&id=o-AIQyMAv9KAgXr7OP25tqJ3GonDqvQCK1eXYzI5QA5hM0&itag=251&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-5aapxquxaxjvh-p5qe%2Csn-p5qs7n76&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=2&pl=20&initcwndbps=1252500&mime=audio%2Fwebm&gir=yes&clen=295267&dur=18.701&lmt=1559546502380639&mt=1562080584&fvip=6&keepalive=yes&c=WEB&txp=5432432&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cmime%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=ALgxI2wwRAIgahDisTbrJoqazA72mCaTG-1QuX1qS9IcbWHe0IEFcicCIElvUXyJL83u9E__VzV_5EUeaWejN1ki9kRlEnNCq7Y_&lsparams=mm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=AHylml4wRgIhAJz3ixqopsu5l8C_jzP-E4EzYnxGBFIC7XGGjD4BRPyIAiEAxoV0lO0XBysnXt8k50Q7F5J7Yig9lS3Xc25XOvHeODo%3D&ratebypass=yes", "player_url": "/yts/jsbin/player_ias-vflxACNZ2/en_US/base.js", "ext": "webm", "format_note": "DASH audio", "acodec": "opus", "abr": 160, "filesize": 295267, "tbr": 129.438, "quality": -1, "vcodec": "none", "downloader_options": {"http_chunk_size": 10485760}, "format": "251 - audio only (DASH audio)", "protocol": "https", "http_headers": {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0", "Accept-Charset": "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7", "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8", "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", "Accept-Language": "en-us,en;q=0.5"}}, {"format_id": "140", "url": "https://r3---sn-5aapxquxaxjvh-p5qe.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1562102342&ei=5nUbXaTpKYu38gSFxpKABg&ip=205.201.245.3&id=o-AIQyMAv9KAgXr7OP25tqJ3GonDqvQCK1eXYzI5QA5hM0&itag=140&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-5aapxquxaxjvh-p5qe%2Csn-p5qs7n76&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=2&pl=20&initcwndbps=1252500&mime=audio%2Fmp4&gir=yes&clen=303964&dur=18.738&lmt=1559546502363003&mt=1562080584&fvip=6&keepalive=yes&c=WEB&txp=5432432&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cmime%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=ALgxI2wwRAIgMZITJIqAH-Ir0zOrbtQBXKXuyRVSlCicdejddbh_EAcCIBsOsXYEBN-qlSa7Ftodnr8gB_7yEP8jJNJNSC-Rf7Jy&lsparams=mm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=AHylml4wRgIhAJz3ixqopsu5l8C_jzP-E4EzYnxGBFIC7XGGjD4BRPyIAiEAxoV0lO0XBysnXt8k50Q7F5J7Yig9lS3Xc25XOvHeODo%3D&ratebypass=yes", "player_url": "/yts/jsbin/player_ias-vflxACNZ2/en_US/base.js", "ext": "m4a", "format_note": "DASH audio", "acodec": "mp4a.40.2", "abr": 128, "container": "m4a_dash", "filesize": 303964, "tbr": 130.404, "quality": -1, "vcodec": "none", "downloader_options": {"http_chunk_size": 10485760}, "format": "140 - audio only (DASH audio)", "protocol": "https", "http_headers": {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0", "Accept-Charset": "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7", "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8", "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", "Accept-Language": "en-us,en;q=0.5"}}, {"format_id": "171", "url": "https://r3---sn-5aapxquxaxjvh-p5qe.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1562102342&ei=5nUbXaTpKYu38gSFxpKABg&ip=205.201.245.3&id=o-AIQyMAv9KAgXr7OP25tqJ3GonDqvQCK1eXYzI5QA5hM0&itag=171&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-5aapxquxaxjvh-p5qe%2Csn-p5qs7n76&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=2&pl=20&initcwndbps=1252500&mime=audio%2Fwebm&gir=yes&clen=320876&dur=18.690&lmt=1559546502459212&mt=1562080584&fvip=6&keepalive=yes&c=WEB&txp=5432432&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cmime%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=ALgxI2wwRgIhANaKnYXGFFDN7w78hbmCC7opUKNB4stV6M4fD8hf6vcAAiEA4FnYWosi8AaEJuyR_fTljVrG10vkAc4MYEDuvn6jgJ8%3D&lsparams=mm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=AHylml4wRgIhAJz3ixqopsu5l8C_jzP-E4EzYnxGBFIC7XGGjD4BRPyIAiEAxoV0lO0XBysnXt8k50Q7F5J7Yig9lS3Xc25XOvHeODo%3D&ratebypass=yes", "player_url": "/yts/jsbin/player_ias-vflxACNZ2/en_US/base.js", "ext": "webm", "acodec": "vorbis", "format_note": "DASH audio", "abr": 128, "filesize": 320876, "tbr": 148.28, "quality": -1, "vcodec": "none", "downloader_options": {"http_chunk_size": 10485760}, "format": "171 - audio only (DASH audio)", "protocol": "https", "http_headers": {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0", "Accept-Charset": "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7", "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8", "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", "Accept-Language": "en-us,en;q=0.5"}}, {"format_id": "278", "url": "https://r3---sn-5aapxquxaxjvh-p5qe.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1562102342&ei=5nUbXaTpKYu38gSFxpKABg&ip=205.201.245.3&id=o-AIQyMAv9KAgXr7OP25tqJ3GonDqvQCK1eXYzI5QA5hM0&itag=278&aitags=133%2C134%2C135%2C136%2C137%2C160%2C242%2C243%2C244%2C247%2C248%2C278%2C298%2C299%2C302%2C303&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-5aapxquxaxjvh-p5qe%2Csn-p5qs7n76&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=2&pl=20&initcwndbps=1252500&mime=video%2Fwebm&gir=yes&clen=219883&dur=18.666&lmt=1559546957289995&mt=1562080584&fvip=6&keepalive=yes&c=WEB&txp=5432432&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Caitags%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cmime%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=ALgxI2wwRQIhAPa2epstA8eMxFspW2eR_DFK48f3df74nhwE3uJjx9YtAiBw0aHV2ydjeh4boYq8XggbP-SO7UeR4wRGPIx6euNduA%3D%3D&lsparams=mm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=AHylml4wRgIhAJz3ixqopsu5l8C_jzP-E4EzYnxGBFIC7XGGjD4BRPyIAiEAxoV0lO0XBysnXt8k50Q7F5J7Yig9lS3Xc25XOvHeODo%3D&ratebypass=yes", "player_url": "/yts/jsbin/player_ias-vflxACNZ2/en_US/base.js", "ext": "webm", "height": 144, "format_note": "144p", "container": "webm", "vcodec": "vp9", "filesize": 219883, "tbr": 96.07, "width": 256, "fps": 30, "quality": -1, "acodec": "none", "downloader_options": {"http_chunk_size": 10485760}, "format": "278 - 256x144 (144p)", "protocol": "https", "http_headers": {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0", "Accept-Charset": "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7", "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8", "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", "Accept-Language": "en-uu...},
{"id": "RzMh3nTheCo", "uploader": "an0nymooose", "uploader_id": "an0nymooose", "uploader_url": "http://www.youtube.com/user/an0nymooose", "channel_id": "UCpclRlEJ2oh6JDEJy68UjKA", "channel_url": "http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCpclRlEJ2oh6JDEJy68UjKA", "upload_date": "20190401", "license": null, "creator": null, "title": "[SFM] Hocus Bogus", "alt_title": null, "thumbnail": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/RzMh3nTheCo/maxresdefault.jpg", "description": "Months and months of work for the adult swim video, sorry. Hopefully you guys will like it, its got all 100% custom models/mapping which is very hard to get together and generate an idea for in SFM (i didnt model it tho, had it all converted). Here's the sad news: it didn't get approved at adult swim (wasn't notified until the video was fully done), but oh well I tried I guess. Sorta didn't want to post this video but I figured I put in a ton of work, but it didn't come out to be as perfect as I wanted, don't hate me pls.\n\nsnapchat: an0nsnap\ntwitter: https://twitter.com/an0nymoooseYT\ninsta: https://www.instagram.com/an0nymooose/\npatreon: https://www.patreon.com/an0nymooose\nSONG: https://soundcloud.com/tregsmusic/flow\nDiscord: https://discord.gg/WPVrE7t\n\nsome neat facts:\n\n-No valve models/textures\n-I was only given 1 model from the start, the rainbow guy (veryman) and told to do whatever, so I picked a song I liked, and sat there for hundreds of hours trying to generate ideas and animate it. By far the most difficult one I've done yet. (thanks Vince M. from adult swim for all the model help, and thank you SterlingFM for the modeling help)\n-a few runescape references in the video. The modified bones to bananas spell is the same as the ingame animation. (Same with the Ancient Magicks spell he casts on the cat)\n- The beard and the bag physics were all hand animated 100%, SFM has no real physics, and the beard itself probably has 700+ keys alone (pls watch and think \"wow nice beard physics an0nmose\").\n- valve please update sfm its incredibly buggy\n- ur kinda hot lollll... ;) add my snapchat ;))\n- https://imgur.com/a/0Yyl3\n\nFAQ:\n\nQ: amonmonoose more like anona-go-NOOSE urself LOL\nA: dude come on wtf\n\nQ: whens the next video!!! i need it NOW NOW NOW\nA: alch urself.\n\nQ: ananaOAONOOmoOOSE wat is CRACKIN!!\nA: bACK, GET BACK NOW", "categories": ["Film & Animation"], "tags": [], "subtitles": {}, "automatic_captions": {}, "duration": 103, "age_limit": 0, "annotations": null, "chapters": null, "webpage_url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RzMh3nTheCo", "view_count": 790679, "like_count": 62408, "dislike_count": 325, "average_rating": 4.9792771, "formats": [{"format_id": "249", "url": "https://r3---sn-5aapxquxaxjvh-p5qe.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1562102345&ei=6XUbXdrLIq6shwaojLuIAg&ip=205.201.245.3&id=o-AJr4pgfPjGzM_f0dYlbAI4kq8ljVvQ0LX1RdcsTivFPV&itag=249&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-5aapxquxaxjvh-p5qe%2Csn-p5qs7n7e&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=2&pl=20&initcwndbps=1252500&mime=audio%2Fwebm&gir=yes&clen=674773&dur=102.961&lmt=1559550315355298&mt=1562080584&fvip=3&keepalive=yes&c=WEB&txp=5531432&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cmime%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=ALgxI2wwRQIgUsDQZKCx1KxfshHZiOz8vZoQuo6GEX5CCqRlxi0_cjICIQD3y4Ev-Zz03f66rcWDI9saUOOGqwwEltU6dRXiDShIQg%3D%3D&lsparams=mm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=AHylml4wRQIhAKmfnwS_dcIMrapCFNs4DYQqRspMTFKcExW_tJ4ORmL7AiBsfQiRa-YjkkDg6xWla-W2Pl0VWtMefpyLkK2e5E3Rzg%3D%3D&ratebypass=yes", "player_url": "/yts/jsbin/player_ias-vflxACNZ2/en_US/base.js", "ext": "webm", "format_note": "DASH audio", "acodec": "opus", "abr": 50, "filesize": 674773, "tbr": 54.492, "quality": -1, "vcodec": "none", "downloader_options": {"http_chunk_size": 10485760}, "format": "249 - audio only (DASH audio)", "protocol": "https", "http_headers": {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0", "Accept-Charset": "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7", "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8", "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", "Accept-Language": "en-us,en;q=0.5"}}, {"format_id": "250", "url": "https://r3---sn-5aapxquxaxjvh-p5qe.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1562102345&ei=6XUbXdrLIq6shwaojLuIAg&ip=205.201.245.3&id=o-AJr4pgfPjGzM_f0dYlbAI4kq8ljVvQ0LX1RdcsTivFPV&itag=250&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-5aapxquxaxjvh-p5qe%2Csn-p5qs7n7e&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=2&pl=20&initcwndbps=1252500&mime=audio%2Fwebm&gir=yes&clen=881079&dur=102.961&lmt=1559550314949272&mt=1562080584&fvip=3&keepalive=yes&c=WEB&txp=5531432&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cmime%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=ALgxI2wwRQIgSBl6Dxy3PQT5ENME-q2PH62YPdYusJCb19tBv5ApgfgCIQDYO3iz1HqsiDPETxXWi4TdXG7gU-N4MU5PUOf0zuKkCQ%3D%3D&lsparams=mm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=AHylml4wRQIhAKmfnwS_dcIMrapCFNs4DYQqRspMTFKcExW_tJ4ORmL7AiBsfQiRa-YjkkDg6xWla-W2Pl0VWtMefpyLkK2e5E3Rzg%3D%3D&ratebypass=yes", "player_url": "/yts/jsbin/player_ias-vflxACNZ2/en_US/base.js", "ext": "webm", "format_note": "DASH audio", "acodec": "opus", "abr": 70, "filesize": 881079, "tbr": 72.143, "quality": -1, "vcodec": "none", "downloader_options": {"http_chunk_size": 10485760}, "format": "250 - audio only (DASH audio)", "protocol": "https", "http_headers": {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0", "Accept-Charset": "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7", "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8", "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", "Accept-Language": "en-us,en;q=0.5"}}, {"format_id": "140", "url": "https://r3---sn-5aapxquxaxjvh-p5qe.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1562102345&ei=6XUbXdrLIq6shwaojLuIAg&ip=205.201.245.3&id=o-AJr4pgfPjGzM_f0dYlbAI4kq8ljVvQ0LX1RdcsTivFPV&itag=140&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-5aapxquxaxjvh-p5qe%2Csn-p5qs7n7e&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=2&pl=20&initcwndbps=1252500&mime=audio%2Fmp4&gir=yes&clen=1667731&dur=102.980&lmt=1559550314605164&mt=1562080584&fvip=3&keepalive=yes&c=WEB&txp=5531432&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cmime%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=ALgxI2wwRQIhAIUKI4wpVTVGIzvGrXyXMguSmHL3L6fsJrafsA50xCBrAiB4nui2-LZ5Ud-3ObvK7IMwK4G-n7kyYZTlpuOSgmUZDQ%3D%3D&lsparams=mm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=AHylml4wRQIhAKmfnwS_dcIMrapCFNs4DYQqRspMTFKcExW_tJ4ORmL7AiBsfQiRa-YjkkDg6xWla-W2Pl0VWtMefpyLkK2e5E3Rzg%3D%3D&ratebypass=yes", "player_url": "/yts/jsbin/player_ias-vflxACNZ2/en_US/base.js", "ext": "m4a", "format_note": "DASH audio", "acodec": "mp4a.40.2", "abr": 128, "container": "m4a_dash", "filesize": 1667731, "tbr": 130.43, "quality": -1, "vcodec": "none", "downloader_options": {"http_chunk_size": 10485760}, "format": "140 - audio only (DASH audio)", "protocol": "https", "http_headers": {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0", "Accept-Charset": "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7", "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8", "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", "Accept-Language": "en-us,en;q=0.5"}}, {"format_id": "171", "url": "https://r3---sn-5aapxquxaxjvh-p5qe.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1562102345&ei=6XUbXdrLIq6shwaojLuIAg&ip=205.201.245.3&id=o-AJr4pgfPjGzM_f0dYlbAI4kq8ljVvQ0LX1RdcsTivFPV&itag=171&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-5aapxquxaxjvh-p5qe%2Csn-p5qs7n7e&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=2&pl=20&initcwndbps=1252500&mime=audio%2Fwebm&gir=yes&clen=1671555&dur=102.929&lmt=1559550315664049&mt=1562080584&fvip=3&keepalive=yes&c=WEB&txp=5531432&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cmime%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=ALgxI2wwRQIgLKxgnDmzVwWd9w3s51bFKzAy0CCdTspdhv0PcSQK-5ACIQCRYQWoboJTU9PtChvn02-tWBOjkor0JHNwu-UDG1I0jw%3D%3D&lsparams=mm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=AHylml4wRQIhAKmfnwS_dcIMrapCFNs4DYQqRspMTFKcExW_tJ4ORmL7AiBsfQiRa-YjkkDg6xWla-W2Pl0VWtMefpyLkK2e5E3Rzg%3D%3D&ratebypass=yes", "player_url": "/yts/jsbin/player_ias-vflxACNZ2/en_US/base.js", "ext": "webm", "acodec": "vorbis", "format_note": "DASH audio", "abr": 128, "filesize": 1671555, "tbr": 142.703, "quality": -1, "vcodec": "none", "downloader_options": {"http_chunk_size": 10485760}, "format": "171 - audio only (DASH audio)", "protocol": "https", "http_headers": {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0", "Accept-Charset": "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7", "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8", "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", "Accept-Language": "en-us,en;q=0.5"}}, {"format_id": "251", "url": "https://r3---sn-5aapxquxaxjvh-p5qe.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1562102345&ei=6XUbXdrLIq6shwaojLuIAg&ip=205.201.245.3&id=o-AJr4pgfPjGzM_f0dYlbAI4kq8ljVvQ0LX1RdcsTivFPV&itag=251&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-5aapxquxaxjvh-p5qe%2Csn-p5qs7n7e&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=2&pl=20&initcwndbps=1252500&mime=audio%2Fwebm&gir=yes&clen=1710085&dur=102.961&lmt=1559550315663826&mt=1562080584&fvip=3&keepalive=yes&c=WEB&txp=5531432&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cmime%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=ALgxI2wwRQIhAMME64zEj8EghuSDrqRk8JvT8pldDEugH-RV5X3U-VmOAiBa4Q1YZ5v3Kfbn9pY2jstCIlbnTfeCoWa5mVAOy-7eYw%3D%3D&lsparams=mm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=AHylml4wRQIhAKmfnwS_dcIMrapCFNs4DYQqRspMTFKcExW_tJ4ORmL7AiBsfQiRa-YjkkDg6xWla-W2Pl0VWtMefpyLkK2e5E3Rzg%3D%3D&ratebypass=yes", "player_url": "/yts/jsbin/player_ias-vflxACNZ2/en_US/base.js", "ext": "webm", "format_note": "DASH audio", "acodec": "opus", "abr": 160, "filesize": 1710085, "tbr": 142.97, "quality": -1, "vcodec": "none", "downloader_options": {"http_chunk_size": 10485760}, "format": "251 - audio only (DASH audio)", "protocol": "https", "http_headers": {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0", "Accept-Charset": "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7", "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xx...},
]
```

I know I can retrieve the last lines of a large file quickly with PowerShell by using `gc nosql.db | select -tail 1` but is there a way to insert a line above the tail without reading and writing the entire file?

**Updated**

This is my script, updated with the correct answer:

```
Write-Host "Searching for and downloading videos . . . "
if(![System.IO.File]::Exists('.\database.js')){
    Set-Content -Path .\database.js -Value "const database = [
]"
}
$PSDefaultParameterValues['Out-File:Encoding'] = 'utf8'
youtube-dl.exe --config-location config.txt --print-json | foreach {
    $stream = [IO.File]::OpenWrite('.\database.js')
    $stream.SetLength($stream.Length - 4)
    $stream.Close()
    $stream.Dispose()

    $_ + ",
]" | Add-Content .\database.js
}
Read-Host -Prompt "Done, press Enter to exit"
```

Comment: Have you considered _not_ using a flat file for your "nosql JSON database"? :-)

Comment: The JSON output by youtube-dl is difficult to process, because its keys change depending on the website (It can be used for other websites besides YouTube). I'm trying to format it this way so it can be imported into a local html file (my viewer) without setting up a webserver because of cross origin protections or using inconsistent options between browsers.

Comment: No, I meant: have you considered using an actual database instead of txt files? SQLite should suffice

Comment: Yeah, thats what I was getting at. There are a lot of columns that would be different depending on external factors when running application + SQLite doesn't solve my primary problem which is reading the database in the local html viewer. This format is flexible and suits my needs better.

Comment: Create a key column from the site key + site-specific id, then throw the entire JSON blob into a second column :)

Comment: Yeah, thats not a bad way to store the data but it doesn't fit my specific use case scenario. I've already spent time thinking about these things which is why I asked my specific question. I'd rather hear how I can or can't solve the question I asked then other suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well try this:

```
$content = "THIS IS A NEW INSERT :D"

$stream = [IO.File]::OpenWrite('.\Desktop\testJS.js')
$stream.SetLength($stream.Length - 6)
$stream.Close()
$stream.Dispose()

$content | Add-Content .\Desktop\testJS.js
"]" | Add-Content .\Desktop\testJS.js
```

I remove the last line which is the "]" then I add the new content as well as the "]".

Hope it helps! BR

Comment: Tried it on my large test file and it seemed to do the trick. Only problem is I think it is removing too many bytes and not inserting on a new line. The new data has been placed over some of the previous line. This is what the last line of my file looks like after running:
`..."release_date": null, "playlist": THIS IS A NEW INSERT :D\n]`

Comment: @FunkyKong
Interessting. I made a .js file with the supplied content and it worked fine for me.
Perhaps you could provide me with your example file somehow.

Comment: I'm sure I can tweak it to perfection later. The more important issue I need to address is how to run this code every time youtube-dl prints JSON. Because it is a one line call I need to send what it prints to a function and then run this code inside.

Comment: ```$expression = "youtube-dl.exe --config-location config.txt --print-json"```
```$content = Invoke-Expression $expression```
Perhaps this will do the trick? you only need to check if $content isn't empty -> else run the code and empty $content

Comment: Back to the issue where bytes were cut off. My Out-File Endoding is set to utf8, is it different for you?

Comment: @FunkyKong Still having Issues on the bytesize?

Comment: Nope, 4 bytes was the appropriate size for my encoding.